# Laravel 4.1 Streaming Video

Tags: php, html, laravel-4, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using Laravel 4.1 to build a little side project. The basic idea is to create a site that will allow me to watch videos I have on my own server. I have figured out the authentication part. And I'm using Flysystem to gain access to my servers filesystem outside of the document root.

Basically, my question is 'How do I stream video with Laravel?'

If possible, I'd like to be able to use videojs or jwplayer or something like that. Not a requirement, just throwing it out there.

If I need to provide more detail or any sort of controller information let me know, I would post it but, I don't know exactly WHAT I should post at the moment.

**Update**

So I don't think I worded my question well enough. I've also made some changes to my code and therefore have a better understanding of what I am trying to do. So, with that in mind, I'll get to it.

Client side I have NO problems. I understand how I'm going to solve that problem.

Server Side. The question remains, how do I craft a `Response` to ensure when I hit `mydomain.com/mymovie.mp4` the response is properly formulated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a streaming response:

```
$file_location = __DIR__ . '/path/to/file.ext';

return Response::stream(function () use ($file_location) {
   $stream = fopen($file_location, 'r');
   fpassthru($stream);
}, 200, $headers);
```

The headers need to include mime-type and file size. There are various functions that will give you the values for that. Alternatively you can use a package like Flysystem (shameless promotion) to get these values, making that job a bit easier. Example:

```
$stream = $filesystem->readStream($location);
$headers = [
    "Content-Type" => $fs->getMimetype($location),
    "Content-Length" => $fs->getSize($location),
    "Content-disposition" => "attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"",
];

return Response::stream(function () use ($stream) {
    fpassthru($stream);
}, 200, $headers);
```

Answer (score -4):

Laravel is just a framework. It doesn't have much to do with what the site does. It just helps you create and manage the site better and faster.

If you want to stream videos on your site, you should focus on `<video>` tag of `html`.

Comment: I am comfortable client side. I want to know how to craft a Laravel `Response` so it gives me a video.